# Java Operations in Math Equations

Tags: java

I am trying to write a program that calculates the distance of a projectile, but the distance returned is not coming out correct. I am familiar with operator precedence in Java, but I am not sure why I am not getting the correct distance. For angle = 22, velocity = 35, and height = 10 I expect to get 75.54 but instead I am getting 42.03.

Are there obvious mistakes in my code that are causing this?

```
public class FootballDistanceCalculator {

    public static final double GRAVITATIONAL_ACCELERATION = 32.174;  
    /**
     * Calculates the distance a projectile travels
     * 
     * @param angle angle at which projectile is thrown in degrees
     * @param velocity initial velocity of projectile in miles/hour
     * @param height initial height of projectile in feet
     * @return distance traveled by projectile in feet
     */ 
    public static double calculateDistance(double angle, double velocity, double height) {
        double angleRadians = Math.toRadians(angle);
        double vCosineThetaOverG = (velocity * (Math.cos(angleRadians))) / GRAVITATIONAL_ACCELERATION ;
        double vSinTheta = velocity * (Math.sin(angleRadians));
        double vSinThetaSquared = (Math.pow(vSinTheta, 2));
        double twoGravHeight = (2 * GRAVITATIONAL_ACCELERATION * height);
        double radical = Math.sqrt((vSinThetaSquared + twoGravHeight));
        double distance = vCosineThetaOverG * (vSinTheta + radical);
        return distance;
    } 
}
```

This is the equation I am basing this program off of:

> *d* = (*v* cos(θ) / *g*)(*v* sin(θ) + √(*v* sin(θ)<sup>2</sup> + 2 *g* *h*))
>
> *v* = velocity
> *g* = gravitational acceleration
> *h* = height

The problem turned out to be a units conversion issue as indicated in the comments.

I had to take my velocity parameter and multiply by feet per mile (5280) and divide by seconds per hour (3600) to get my units to match.

Comment: I have downvoted this question because there is no evidence of any debugging performed on this code.  Please [edit] your question to show us what your debugging has uncovered, as well as a specific question about a specific line of code.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Weird enough, I got 106...

Comment: Are your units all consistent?   height in meters, v in meters/sec, g in meters/sec^2

Comment: I also got `106.9310020929529` @GalAbra

Comment: Are you using correct value of g? Why is it 32.174? I think the problem here is mainly with physics knowledge. You are failing to convert the units to bring them in the same metric system.

Comment: @JoeC interesting, I definitely mentioned a specific example of what was an expected output, what I returned for what parameters. The code compiled and produced an output that was unexpected. That is my debugging. And the question was specific - did I miss anything in regards to operators or precedence.

Comment: Also is your sign correct on g?

Comment: I am curious to know in which metric system the value of `g` is 32.174.

Comment: @Jasonc200 What you just described is not debugging.  Debugging involves using the tools that come with your IDE to determine which specific line is not performing the correct calculation.

Comment: @JoeC That makes sense. I am not permitted to use an IDE for this exercise.

Comment: In that case, read the link I offered in the first instance for further debugging tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calculating in metric but your `g` constant is in feet per second per second.